# Is it possible to stream websocket datafrom Python to Excel using xlWings?

Tags: python, excel, websocket, stream

Currently i'm only familiar using REST with Excel VBA + a Json Parser....  but for optimum efficiency i want to use websocket data. Ive seen many examples of Websocket Data being pulled into python but not much about getting it over to Excel where it can be used in a more friendly UI.

Thanks

A bit of research led me to xlWings.